# How to extract urls and text from html markup with regex

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

```
<!-- This Div repeated in HTML with different properties value -->

<div style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:220px; top:785px; width:347px; height:18px; z-index:36">

<!-- Only Unique Thing is This in few pages -->
<a href="http://link.domain.com/?id=123" target="_parent">

<!-- OR in some pages Only Unique Thing is This, ending with mp3 extension -->
<a href="http://domain.com/song-title.mp3" target="_parent">

    <!-- This Div also repeated multiple in HTML -->

    <FONT style="font-size:10pt" color=#000000 face="Tahoma">
        <DIV><B>Harjaiyaan</B> - Nandini Srikar</DIV>
    </FONT>
</a>

</DIV>
```

We have very dirty html markup, its generated by some program or application. We want to extract 'Urls' from this code and as well as 'Text'.

in a `href` we are using two types urls, Url 1 pattern: 'http://link.domain.com/id=123', Url 2   pattern: 'http://domain.com/sons-title.mp3'

in the first match, we are specific pattern for but in second url we have not pattern just urls ending with '.mp3' extension.

Is there some function to extract `url` from this pattern and text code as well?

**Note:**  without DOM, is there any way to match a href and between text with regular expression ? preg_match ?

Comment: There's no magic function that does all the job for you. You'll have to write code that does what you want. Use a DOM parser such as DOMDocument to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class and proceed like this.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); //<------- Pass ur HTML source here
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {

        echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
        echo $tag->nodeValue; // to get the content in between of tags...

}
```

Comment: Just tried this, it works great. Though you might want to change this line to: echo $tag->getAttribute('href');

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Shankar Damodaran's answer:

```
$html = file_get_contents('source.htm');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {

    if (strstr($tag->getAttribute('href'),'?id=') !== false) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('href') . "<br>\n";
    }

}
```

Then do the same for the MP3:

```
$html = file_get_contents('source.htm');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {

    if (strstr($tag->getAttribute('href'),'.mp3') !== false) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('href') . "<br>\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but its show warning, like "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : td
Notice: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Namespace prefix fb
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag fb:comment"

Comment: You need to load the $html file contents correctly.

Comment: Try saving the page you are reading the urls from as an .html file and open it with file_get_contents('source.htm') to debug it first. Delete the unnecessary stuff to make it simpler to debug.

Comment: without DOM, is there any way to match a href and between text with regular expression ? preg_match ?